# how do I browse to files on my external sdcard when the phone is connected using MTP?

Tags: external-sd, storage, file-system

I have connected my phone to my computer (Win7) using MTP. I can browse to the H:\ drive and see things like `music`,`amazonmp3`, `alogcat` and so on. But when I use my phone's file manager to try and find those folders, I'm unable to. I'm trying to go to things like:

- `/storage/emulated/0` - doesn't have the same files
- `/storage/sdcard0` - empty
- `/storage/sdcard1` - empty

Among others. No luck though. What I'm really after is being able to store a [KeePass db on my phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.keepass&hl=en) and access it from my PC from time to time. To do that I need to be able to find it on the (external) SD card. How can I do that?

Comment: It's usually found at `/sdcard` – but depending on the device (and its manufacturer), that might differ. Another important criterium might be whether you're talking about the internal (emulated) or external (physical) SD card. So could you please [edit] your question and add those details? What also helps is running the `mount` command from either a terminal app or via `adb shell`, and provide the output.

Comment: It was tagged external-sd, I thought that clarified it.

Comment: You won't believe how often tags are misplaced. Added to that, your question text lists a bunch of locations applying to the internal (emulated) SD card, which might be confusing :) Thanks for clarification! // Have you checked with the `mount` command? That would help us helping you.

Comment: Don't get it wrong but are you certain you connected your device in MTP and not UMS? `H:/`  would be visible for block devices or network shares mounted as block devices. Devices connected using MTP shows up as "Portable Devices" in Win7. At least this is how all devices behaves in my Win7.

Comment: @Firelord ack, you might be right. I will research.

Comment: @jcollum Please answer your question if you've solved it, or update the question so that somebody may see it and help you out. :)

Comment: @Firelord give me some time here man, this is not a priority in my life

Answer (score -1):

That's probably cause your phone automaticly mounts sdcards in MTP, when your phone is in MTP mode you apparently can't use your file manager.

Comment: What you write is correct for UMS (USB Mass Storage) only. That was one of the reasons Android switched to MTP, which is more like a "network share": you can access files on both ends simultaneously, they no longer "disappear" from the device.